# "Modal hide fade" preventing inner chart div from showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

In need of some help, I'm rather stuck. what I want achieve is, at the click of a button, a pop-up appears and has a bar chart showing based on the data sent. So far what I know is that the chart plots without a problem, however when I put it into the pop-up modal, it doesn't show.

```
<div class="modal hide fade"  id=" PopUpModal" aria-hidden="true" style="float: initial; width :80%" role="dialog">


        <h3 data-bind="text: title"></h3>
        <hr />

        <div id="ChartModal" class="chart" style="width: 780px; height: 300px;"> </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see, the chart modal is inside the pop-up div. When the pop-up button is clicked, the pop-up modal shows empty except for the title and hr line. However you can see the space that is occupied by the chart modal, but its blank. When I take the chart modal outside the pop-up, it shows fine. When I remove 'class="modal hide fade" ', the chart shows inside the pop-up, however the pop-up is no longer a pop-up, but a div on the page.

Anyone see what I might be doing wrong? I'm  not sure which bootstrap div "class" attributes I could use that would enable me to have the pop up hidden until clicked (I use $('#Pop-Up').modal('show'); in the js to change from hide to visible) and also allow the chart to show inside it.

Comment: call the chart function, after the modal has been displayed

Comment: It happens, Me too faced this same problem i m using fusion charts

Comment: thanks Jake!! Worked a charm!!

Comment: Welcome LeloKunene:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably because of chart plugin. Since chart is inside a hidden object plugin doesn't work. You must trigger chart plugin inside the modal callback function. I mean after modal window is displayed then run chart plugin not on page load.

Comment: Thanks Ergec!! That' exactly what I did.. my pop-up call back was after the plugin code.. all I just did now was put it before it and voila!!! Many thanks!